# Read file + download web page in same loop?

Tags: vb.net

This is a newbie question.

In a loop, I need to read a list of URLs from a text file, download the web page, and search for a bit of text using a regex.

I used the following code, with DownloadStringAsync() to avoid freezing the UI, but it triggers the error "WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.":

```
Private Sub AlertStringDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        Dim Content As String
        Content = CStr(e.Result)

        'Here, use regex to extract token
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Read URLs from txt file
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "sites.txt"

    Dim webClient As New WebClient
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    AddHandler webClient.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf AlertStringDownloaded

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            Line = objReader.ReadLine

            '"WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations."
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(Line))

            'Go to AlertStringDownloaded
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If

End Sub
```

Does someone know of an alternative?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Apparently, the solution is to force the application to pause until the current page is downloaded. Is there a better way than using DoEvents?

```
Dim Busy As Boolean = False

Private Sub AlertStringDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        ...
      Busy = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ...
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            ...
            '"WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations."
            Busy = True
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(Line))
            'Better way to pause until done downloading current page?
            Do While Busy
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
            Loop
        Loop
    Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a program that does two things at once you should look into threading. (Or if you've got the CTP of the next version of Visual Studio then [Asynchrony](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx)). See the [blog post here for a simple tutorial on creating a multi-threaded app](http://chrishaas.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/creating-a-simple-multi-threaded-vb-net-application/).